# Add a condition to MySQL JOIN query: WHERE a column equals to result of a query

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce

In an ecommerce website I have to change a query.
This website has multiple prices for each product, depending on the quantity chosen by customer.

If quantity of a product in the cart is more than a specific number, its cost would be lower.
For example if the quantity is 1 the price would be $10, if the quantity is 20, the price of each product would reduce to $8.

here is my table structures:

```
prices
id | product_id | num | price
1  | 111111     | 1   | 10
2  | 111111     | 20  | 8
3  | 111111     | 100 | 5
4  | 222222     | 1   | 42
5  | 222222     | 50  | 35

cart

id | factor_id | product_id | quantity
1  | 1         | 111111       | 30
2  | 1         | 222222       | 3
3  | 2         | 222222       | 1
4  | 2         | 111111       | 2
```

In this query:

```
SELECT prices.price AS price, prices.product_id AS product_id FROM cart
LEFT JOIN prices ON prices.product_id = cart.product_id  
WHERE prices.num='1'
AND cart.id='$cart_id'
```

I want to change `WHERE prices.num='1'` line. Price must get selected according to the quantity of that product in cart.

I thought something like this could help, but I don't know how to use it because each cart can have various products:

```
SELECT (prices.num - cart.quantity) as nearest, prices.num as priceForThatQuantity
FROM prices
WHERE nearest > 0
ORDER BY nearest ASC
LIMIT 1
```

and then:

```
WHERE prices.num='1' = priceForThatQuantity
```

I think I must use some kind of a JOIN...

EDIT:
Product `111111` is $10 if quantity is less than 20, $8 for quantities between 20 and 100 and $5 for more than 100 pieces.

Comment: By how much is each decremented for each additional product? Is that a table somwhere? Or a fixed rate?

Comment: unfortunately decrements are not fixed. They are stored in `prices` table. in `num` column.

Comment: Please provide some sample data, is it a percentage or dollar amount? Are there limits to the number of discounts? Is it decremented for each? There's a whole lot that is not defined here.

Comment: can a product have more than 2 prices?

Comment: as you can see in `prices` table `111111` product is $10 if quantity is less than 20, $8 for quantities between 20 and 100 and $5 for more than 100 pieces.

Comment: Not related to your question. But using your ranges of prices. Buying 16 products `111111` at 10$ each is the same as buy 20 at 8$ each = 160$

Comment: Would anyone ever order 16 or 17 (no.) of item 111111? If so, what would you expect to happen in those instances?

Comment: And what's a factor_id?

Comment: @Strawberry Yes they can order 16 items of product `111111`, the price will be calculated like 16*10$. I just need `price` value from this query which is 10$. factor_id represent a specific order. Each order can have multiple products.

Comment: But then they're missing out on 4 free items :-(

Comment: Believe me I've seen people buying 19 pieces of such a product! But this is only a sample data!!!

Answer (score 1):

Start with this query:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM cart c
 JOIN prices p
   ON c.product_id = p.product_id
  AND c.quantity >= p.num
```

As you can see for product `111111`     30 > 1 and also 30 > 20 so you need to group those and get the min price to get $8

```
 SELECT c.product_id, 
        c.quantity,
        MIN(p.price) as price
 FROM cart c
 JOIN prices p
   ON c.product_id = p.product_id
  AND c.quantity >= p.num 
 GROUP BY  c.product_id, 
           c.quantity
```

Answer (score 1):

What uniquely identifies a row in `cart` ?  A combination of `(id,product_id)`?

One option would be a JOIN with a GROUP BY and a MIN() aggregate to pick out the minimum price from the matching rows in `cart`. But without some guaranteed uniqueness for rows in `cart`, I'm hesitant to add a `GROUP BY` to the query at the risk of collapsing rows.

So the safer bet would be a correlated subquery in the SELECT list. (This is less optimal for large sets, but given the example query is retrieving a single cart, and there probably are a reasonably small number of items in a cart, and with suitable index available on `price` table, this won't hurt us too badly in terms of performance, like it would with a large set.

We could do something like this:

```
 SELECT ( SELECT price.unit_price
            FROM price
           WHERE price.product_id = cart.product_id
             AND price.num       <= cart.quantity
           ORDER BY price.num DESC
           LIMIT 1
        ) AS unit_price
      , cart.product_id AS product_id
   FROM cart
  WHERE cart.id = 'foo'
```

Note that there is a potential to match multiple rows in the `price` table, if the cart has a quantity of '20', we could match rows in `price` for `num` values of `15`, `12`, `6`, `3`, `1` ... so we need a way to "pick out" which of those rows to use. One approach is to order the matching rows by `num` in descending order, and take only the first row. That's what the query above is doing, with the ORDER BY and LIMIT 1 in the subquery.

---

Back to the JOIN option...

Unless there is guaranteed to be row in `price` with a `num` value that matches every possible value of `quantity`, we probably need to look for the row in price that has a `num` value that is less than or equal to the `quantity`.

With that condition in a JOIN, there's potential to match multiple rows. The following query has the potential to return duplicated `product_id` from the `cart`,  this doesn't return a "correct" result, but will demonstrates the result we get with a JOIN operation when `quantity` "matches" multiple values of `num`...

```
SELECT cart.product_id
     , price.num
     , price.unit_price
  FROM cart 
  JOIN price 
    ON price.product_id  = cart.product_id
   AND price.num        <= cart.quantity 
 WHERE cart.id = 'foo'
 ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

We can use a `GROUP BY` to collapse the rows and use an aggregate function to pick out the lowest price. (Assuming that larger quantities produce a lower price. Assuming that the unit price is never lower for a smaller quantity, we can get the highest value of `num` that we matched along with the lowest value of `price`

```
SELECT cart.product_id
     , MAX(price.num)
     , MIN(price.unit_price)
  FROM cart 
  JOIN price 
    ON price.product_id  = cart.product_id
   AND price.num        <= cart.quantity 
 WHERE cart.id = 'foo'
 GROUP BY cart.id, cart.product_id
 ORDER BY cart.id, cart.product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
SELECT prices.price AS price, prices.product_id AS product_id FROM cart
LEFT JOIN prices ON prices.product_id = cart.product_id  
WHERE prices.num in ( SELECT quantity FROM cart WHERE cart.id='$cart_id')
AND cart.id='$cart_id'
```

Comment: It's not what I want, a user can order 16 pieces of product 111111, and in database there are rows for 1 or more pieces, 20 or more pieces... . In this case price for 1 or more pieces is calculated, obviously because 16 pieces is less than 20.